# How to edit xsl to keep formatting, when retrieving data from database?

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, xslt

I have the following xsl code snippet, which retrieves data from the db, and creates a table on the jsp page:

```
<xsl:template match="Rows">
    <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
        <tr>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">LightRow</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">DarkRow</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">row_<xsl:value-of select="Field[@ColumnName='ID']"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="OnMouseOver">mouseHandler(this.id, 'over');</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="OnMouseOut">mouseHandler(this.id, 'out');</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="onClick">formSubmitBase('<xsl:value-of select="Field[@ColumnName='ID']"/>');</xsl:attribute>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Field[@ColumnName='ID']"/>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Field[@ColumnName='NAME']"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Field[@ColumnName='STATUS']"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Field[@ColumnName='DESCRIPTION']"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

On the JSP page, there is a `textarea` input field, which collects the DESCRIPTION data and it is important that the description typed here should reserve new lines. I can see, that in the database the new line formattings are ok, if I copy the text and paste it (from plsql developer) into notepad, the new lines are ok. But after populating a table to the JSP page with the code above, the description part looses the new line characters.

This table generated with xsl is on the same page, where the input fields are, and when 1 row is clicked, the input fields are refilled with the data. The problem is, that after submitting a new row, and clicking it to refill the input fields, the new lines are gone.

I'm using oracle db. How are the new lines `\r\n` are represented there? How can I transform the XSL DESCRIPTION part, to keep the new lines, when the description is inserted back into the `textarea` input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any `textarea` in your snippet, so assuming you are talking about

```
<td>
    <xsl:value-of select="Field[@ColumnName='DESCRIPTION']"/>
</td>
```

then change it to

```
<td>
    <pre style="white-space: pre;"><xsl:value-of select="Field[@ColumnName='DESCRIPTION']"/></pre>
</td>
```

or perhaps

```
<td>
    <pre style="white-space: pre-wrap;"><xsl:value-of select="Field[@ColumnName='DESCRIPTION']"/></pre>
</td>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space?v=example